# how to pass std::unique_ptr in MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Is there way to pass `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` via MPI send/recieve? Is there any way to send an object of a class in MPI, 
I know it is possible to pass structure but how about objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Different MPI processes have different address spaces. Pointers, including C++ smart pointers, have no sensible meaning for a different process - so it does not make sense to transmit them.

Instead you need to transmit the underlying objects. One way to do this, is by using serialization and [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/mpi.html).

Eventually you have to think about parallel data structures, which is a complex topic and there is no general recommendation.